# Как во фрагменте проверить изменилось ли значение SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences

Хочу, чтобы фрагмент, например, каждые 2 секунды сверял значение из `SharedPreferences` и выполнял определенное действие или как можно по другому реализовать ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы контролировать изменения в `SharedPreferences` на него можно повесить слушатель. Слушатель будет срабатывать каждый раз, когда в экземпляр настроек, к которым он подключен будут вносится любые изменения:

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment implements  SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

SharedPreferences prefs;

....

prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

   @Override
   public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

     if (key.equals("some_key")) {

        // действия при изменении значения в ключе some_key

     }
   }
}
```

где *some_key* - определенный ключ в настройках (ячейка для сохранения значений)
 *sharedPreferences* - экземпляр настроек. Из него можно получить конкретное измененное значение.

параметр переданный колбэком `String key` это тот ключ, в котором произошли изменения.

[Официальная документация](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Listening) по вопросу и рекомендации по использованию.

Comment: мне нужно сравнить int, Как мне правильно сделать `if (numbers != PREF_NUMB_NUMBERS)`

Comment: А все спасибо !

Answer (score 2):

Может вам поможет [OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html)?