# Сохранение данных SharedPreferences в момент работы

Tags: android, уведомления, android-alarm-manager

Есть диалог в котором есть выбор интервала уведомлений. При клике на элемент, или при закрытии диалога, сохраняю значении.. Данные успешно сохраняются . И вот проблема в том, что изменения интервала вступает в силу только после перезапуска приложения. То есть, например, в момент запуска интервал стоит 2 мин, и вот меняю значение на 5 мин, и последующие уведомления приходят каждый 2 мин, несмотря что изменил интервал. В MainActivity (onCreate) у меня есть Alarm, видимо дело в нем.  Мне как-то нужно перезапустить активити при закрытии диалога или сам Alarm, чтобы значение alarm`а изменилось. Но не знаю как, и как лучше это сделать.
п.с Activity перезапускать тоже не хотелось.

MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  intervalNotify = IntervalSharedPref.getIntervalChoise("interval");
  AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmService.class);
  PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
    this, 
    100, 
    intent, 
    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
  );
  am.cancel(pi);
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    am.setRepeating(
       AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
       System.currentTimeMillis(), 
       intervalNotify, 
       pi
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: а в чем проблема сохранить данные в памяти, вы вроде как в правильную сторону начали смотреть?)

Comment: Не совсем понял. Вы говорите сохранить в Bundle, а после оттудого вытаскивать значение? Так значение изменится только после пересоздания Activity. Допустим пользователь не свернул, не закрыл приложение, а просто изменил  значение интервала?   Или я не так понял))

Comment: вы знаете что такое sharedpreferences?

Comment: Знаю. Я и пользуюсь им вроде в данном коде

Comment: Нужно вынести этот код в отдельный метод и вызывать его и в `onCreate`, и после изменения значения интервала.

Comment: Вопрос решен. Спасибо @woesss!

Comment: можно так же [повесить слушатель](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/534751/177345) на изменение определенного ключа в преференсах, когда слушатель сработает, выполнять код по изменению интервала

Comment: @pavlofff можно, но он работает как-то по особенному, по своему... аля захотел - запустил слушатель, и также захотел - не запустил слушатель. Note: This callback will not be triggered when preferences are cleared via Editor#clear().